# Redirect a subdomain to a directory with vhosts

Tags: linux, vhosts

I'd like to redirect a subdomain to a user directory.

So I've tried this config, but it seems redirect to the root folder.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName epnet.fr
    ServerAlias *.epnet.fr

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.epnet\.fr
    RewriteCond /home/%1/apps/ -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]
    <Directory /home>
            Options Includes FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For example, I've a user 'tiste', I'd like to redirect tiste.epnet.fr to /home/tiste/apps/ and then, any pages of the website which are on apps/ will be accessible tiste.epnet.fr/index.php

Thanks !

Comment: Enable logging for mod_rewrite, and Apache will tell you step-by-step exactly how it's processing your directives.

Comment: I don't really understand what %{HTTP_HOST} stands for

Comment: HTTP_HOST is the domain name being requested by the browser. So if a user goes to `http://tiste.epnet.fr/foo/bar` then HTTP_HOST will be set to tiste.epnet.fr.

Comment: So do you have any idea about a vhosts which can answer to my question ? Thanks a lot.